# Distinguish between writeTimeout,readTimeout and connectTimeout in Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to post some json string to some URL. I am getting Exception as

```
 Exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to
```

searched lot regarding this issue people are suggesting to increase and decrease timeout parameters in retrofit. I want to know difference between writeTimeout, readTimeout and connectTimeout. So that i can trigger SocketTimeoutException.  here my retro client.

```
    public static Retrofit getClient() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
//.authenticator(new Authen()).

        readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
                        connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
                        addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(DefinesClass.ITS_URL)
//                .baseUrl("https://reqres.in")
//                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();


    }
```

Is there any way i can sort that exception help guys?

Comment: Timeout of 20 Seconds, is way too bad! Your server is not responding, you should be debugging your server not the increasing timeout at your client.
You need to find out the reason why your server is not responding.

Comment: @AbhijithShivaswamy I increased time to 5 to 10 minutes even the same exception i am getting ..but the server guy is telling server is online ..url is working

Comment: Well, either his server is not responding or you are trying to connect to a wrong end point.  10 minutes of timeout value is crazy! Don't do that!

Answer (score 14):

SocketTimeOut meaning your client is not able to reach the server. Try to test the WebService in **Postman**.

- The **connect timeout** is the time-out applied to create a TCP
  connection to the HTTP server. If the TCP handshake is not completed in this time, the connection attempt failed.
- The **read timeout** is the time-out applied from the moment you have
  established a connection (So handshaking is done, and the connection can be used). If no data comes from the server in this time-out time,
  the connection is terminated.

same for write timeout we failed to write anything in give time.

Answer (score 5):

Difference between all three methods are as below :

> **connectTimeout :**

Sets the default connect timeout for new connections. A value of 0 means no timeout, otherwise values must be between 1 and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` when converted to milliseconds.

The **`connectTimeout`** is applied when connecting a TCP socket to the target host. The default value is 10 seconds.

> **readTimeout :**

Sets the default read timeout for new connections. A value of 0 means no timeout, otherwise values must be between 1 and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` when converted to milliseconds.

The read timeout is applied to both the TCP socket and for individual read IO operations including on Source of the Response. The default value is 10 seconds.

> **writeTimeout :**

Sets the default write timeout for new connections. A value of 0 means no timeout, otherwise values must be between 1 and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` when converted to milliseconds.

The write timeout is applied for individual write IO operations. The default value is 10 seconds.

---

Source from [here](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/index.html?okhttp3/package-summary.html).